# indexPath of tableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom method to detect a tap on a cell's image. I want to also find the index path of the image's correlating cell, and use it within the function. Here is what I am using:

CellforRowAtIndexPath:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapped = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellImageTapped:)];
tapped.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapped];
```

method im trying to get the index path at:

```
  -(void)cellImageTapped:(id)sender {
   if(videoArray.count > 0){
       Video *currentVideo = [videoArray objectAtIndex:INDEX_PATH_OF_CELL_IMAGE];
     //do some stuff          
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to pass the index path. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Simple way:

- Get the point of touch
- Then get index path of cell at point

The code is:

```
-(void)cellImageTapped:(id)sender {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint point = [tap locationInView:theTableView];

    NSIndexPath *theIndexPath = [theTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];

    if(videoArray.count > 0){
        Video *currentVideo = [videoArray objectAtIndex:theIndexPath];
        //do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend this way to fetch indexPath of cell which has custom subview - (**compatible with iOS 7 as well as all previous versions**)

```
- (void)cellImageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    UIView *parentCell = gestureRecognizer.view.superview;

    while (![parentCell isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
        parentCell = parentCell.superview;
    }

    UIView *parentView = parentCell.superview;

    while (![parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {   // iOS 7 onwards the table cell hierachy has changed.
        parentView = parentView.superview;
    }


    UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)parentView;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)parentCell];

    NSLog(@"indexPath = %@", indexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a tag to the `UIImageView` in your `UITableViewDataSource`'s `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
cell.imageView.tag = indexPath.row;
```

Comment: I actually am, I just didn't list it, but I don't have access to cells within my function.

Comment: You have access to the imageView. Use ((UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender).view.tag in your cellImageTapped: method. The tap gesture recognizer's view is the imageView that was clicked.

Comment: This is assuming that there is only one section in the tableView

Answer (score 1):

Use the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self cellImageTapped:indexPath];
}
```

Then you can pass the index to a function i.e.

```
-(void)cellImageTapped:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Video *currentVideo = [videoArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't called when I tap the cell. Otherwise this would be perfect :(

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the sender's view's tag. Hopefully this will help someone, as I wasted an hour finding the answer.

```
-(void)cellImageTapped:(id)sender {

UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;

            if(videoArray.count > 0){
                NSInteger datIndex = gesture.view.tag;
                Video *currentVideo = [videoArray objectAtIndex:datIndex];
            }

}
```